# Return control after command ends in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, prompt

Apologies for this newbie question but I can't find the answer anywhere.

If I run the command `systemctl` in a SSH terminal accessing an Ubuntu VM in Azure, then it ends with lines 159-187/187 (END), it doesn't return the control and I don't know what key to press to let it continue and finish. I can press Ctrl-C to cancel, but that's probably not the correct way.

```
...........

systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer   loaded active waiting   Daily Cleanup of Temporary

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

179 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
lines 159-187/187 (END)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a general thing, it is specific to the `systemctl` command. Some commands, like `systemctl`, automatically open a pager (programs like `less` or `more`) for their output. That's why you can press <kbd>space</kbd> to load the next page of output.

To exit the pager, just press <kbd>q</kbd>. You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> though, it doesn't really make much difference.

Comment: While I agree that the question claimed over-generality. It is a little bit more general that just `systemctl`. Also (and I am not 100% sure about this) ctrl-C terminates the process that feeds `less` where as `q` asks `less` to terminate.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes, hence "**some** commands, **like** `systemctl`". But it isn't a general thing as stated in the OP (before your edit): "If I run **a** command in a SSH terminal ". As for Ctrl+C, I suspect (but am not sure, you could well be right) that the Ctrl+C is sent to less, and killing less is the signal to stop the process. I don't see how else it would work seeing that pressing `q` also stops the process, so stopping `less` seems sufficient to stop the process. In fact, I would guess the process has already exited and less is simply holding its output.

Comment: Typing Ctrl+C will send SIGINT to every process in the foreground process *group*, which may include the process feeding `less` as well as `less`. Qutting `less` will cause the other program to receive a SIGPIPE signal if it attempts to write any more output, though the process may have already exited if it has finished writing and `less` has read the output.

Comment: @Terdon I totally agree on the extent (or not) of how general this is. As for signals, on my system (however it is set us), `less` is ignoring ctrl-c. It only stops the feeding process. `q` causes it all to stop: (`less` exits, then a cascade of sig-pipes.)